# Can I convert this Mysql query to JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm fairly familiar with SQL but very new to the Java Persistence API.  I'm using JPA through the Play Framework.

I have the following MySql query that I'd like to convert to pure JPA code if I can:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM Rankable a
INNER JOIN Rankable b on a.id < b.id
WHERE 
  a.category_id = ? AND b.category_id = ?
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Comparison c
    WHERE c.lower in (a.id, b.id))
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Comparison c
    WHERE c.higher IN (a.id, b.id))
ORDER BY a.id * rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

The purpose of this query is to select two rows from the Rankable table, but ensure that this specific pair is not present in the Comparison table.

What would be the best way to call a somewhat complicated query like this from Play/JPA?

Comment: At the first glance the query looks pretty much the same as it would in JPA. The only questionnable things I see there is "rand()" and "LIMIT". Naturally "?" would have to be replaced with another syntax for parameters (:param1, etc.). What are the problems apart from that?

Comment: Ok, I can try to find out what the JPA equivalents of rand() and limit are.  Another question is - when I run this JPA query (using JPA.em().createQuery(query)), how do I pull out the results (since the rows won't correspond to an existing class)?

Comment: What's the purpose of `ORDER BY a.id * rand()` in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do a self join in JPA.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/Relationsononeentity.htm)

from the example

```
    @NamedQuery(name="siblings", query="select distinct sibling1 "
    + "from Deity sibling1, Deity sibling2 where "
    + "sibling1.father = sibling2.father "
    + "and sibling1.mother = sibling2.mother "
    + "and sibling2 = ?1 and sibling1 <> ?1"),
```